# Wrapping / Converting .NET libraries to .NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I want to convert my existing ASP.NET API that was built against .NET 4.6 to ASP.NET Core. From little testing I've done, I like what I see with .NET Core - It's faster and gives the opportunity to run on Linux.

But the biggest problem I've encountered is that a lot of open source libraries that were written using the full .NET F/W are still not compatible with it yet (and no information is given if they ever will be). So suddenly .NET Core loses a lot of it's appeal.

My question is if there is any way to do make use of existing nuget libraries in .NET Core? Is there a way to wrap them to make them work? if not, how can a full .NET F/W library can be converted to .NET Core? does it have to be completely re-written?

Comment: Sorry the question is to broad, especially the converting. Run the .NET Portability Analyzer https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1177943e-cfb7-4822-a8a6-e56c7905292b for a hint, but it depends on the case. Some can be ported with a decent amount of work, others may need major rewrite to be compatible. It depends on how much and which api the library uses. Your best bet is to use ASP.NET Core with full .NET Framework and slowly migrate or replace certain libraries with .NET Compatible ones

Comment: .NET Core at this stage won't be able to support your needs. Stick to .NET Framework and wait till the open source projects to migrate with richer API Microsoft exposes in later releases of .NET Core.

Comment: @Tseng ok. I've installed the portability analyzer and ran it on a project I've downloaded from githug. it shows it passes 100%. But that's all it says - does it check specifically for .NET Core? And now that it passes - what's my next move for converting it to .NET Core?

Comment: Mind to name the library? Some libraries that have UWP support can be used "as is", if they don't use windows / windows phone specific features such as UI classes. If the portability analyzer shows no errors, try to add a project.json/*.xproj file into the source and add the target you need (`netstandard1.x`) and compile it

Comment: I've tried on both Facebook sdk package that I cloned from github and PushSharp

Answer (score 0):

You have APIs that is built using full .NET Framework and you want to compile them to .NET Core (CoreFx). This is not manually done by us right now. If you do want, you have to create PCLs.

If you look at the .NET Core documentation, you will find that .NET Core is *small and optimize runtime*. So all the .NET Framework libraries will be recompiled to CoreFx for optimization by .NET Team. The support for all the .NET Framework libraries are expected to by compatible around Q1, Q2 2017 as you can learn more about them [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/07/15/net-core-roadmap/).

There is another possibility, you can also use .NET Framework libraries with .NET Core but it will only be Windows Compatible.

Comment: But the entire point of .NET Core is not to use the full Framework, right? it's the full F/W that makes .NET apps so heavy today? or is there any other advantage to use .NET Core with full F/W?

Comment: It would be better to say that .NET Core is an optimized version of .NET Framework. .NET Framework includes many other sub-frameworks like WPF, Windows Forms and others. You can't use all of these sub-frameworks with .NET Core for now. The first one that you can use is ASPNET Core. You can read more about the ecosystem at my blog below:
http://kjanshair.azurewebsites.net/fundamentals/dotnetcore

Answer (score 0):

> [Is there] any way to do make use of existing nuget libraries in .NET Core?

Yes, as long as those libraries are portable (PCL). Though it's possible that a portable library uses APIs that are not supported on .Net Core, so to try to use such libraries, you need to use `"imports"` in your project.json.

For .Net Framework libraries, a recompilation is necessary (but probably not sufficient).

As an alternative, you could use ASP.NET Core on .Net Framework. That way, you gain some of the performance improvements, while still being able to use all of .Net Framework. But you do lose portability to Linux and Mac OS (unless you count mono).

> Is there a way to wrap [.Net Framework libraries] to make them work [on .Net Core]?

Not as far as I know.

> How can a full .NET F/W library can be converted to .NET Core? Does it have to be completely re-written?

Generally, it doesn't have to be completely rewritten. But you will have to change parts of it that aren't supported on .Net Core.

Though if you wait, the situation will get better, since many APIs that were originally omitted on .Net Core will soon come back. That may be one reason why some library authors are not rushing to support .Net Core.

Comment: 6 years later it does not seem that they are rushing to add missing APIs e.g. `System.Device.Location`

Comment: @PiotrGolacki You're commenting on a seriously outdated answer. Porting of .Net Framework features to .Net Core has been completed a long time ago, so if anything is still missing, it's quite certain it's never going to be added back and you should look for an alternative instead.